# asp.Net unable to render page after publish

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Unable to understand what to do ? Asp.net Page show blank after publish.

**View source:**

```
<form name="ctl00" method="post" action="default.aspx" id="ctl00">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUENTM4MWRk8F3nytDudBWE1y4PycHzuh2S7RY=" />
</div>
</form><head><meta name="keywords" /><meta name="description" /><title>

</title></head>
```

But from Visual Studio It is working perfectly.

**Configuration** 
: .NET 3.5, Windows 7 Pro 64 bit, Ajax Control tool kit. SQL Server, Subsonic. IIS 7.5.7600.16385

Please help.

Comment: Is the `<head>` tag being rendered after the `<form>` tag, inside body? Is it declared that way in the aspx source?

Comment: What are you expecting to see? I can't see any elements in your html that should actually render something onscreen? The only field you have is hidden. the `<head>` _must_ go before the body.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is being displayed fine while running locally but not displaying when published to IIS, you may want to look at your IIS settings (assuming that's what you are using).  Make sure you have IIS set to display error.  This is done in IIS by going to the ASP Properties page.  Expand the Debugging Properties, and make sure "Send Errors To Browser" is set to true, Enable Server-Side Debugging is set to true, and Enable Client Side Debugging is set to true.  Just make sure you reset this all back to false when you're ready to go live as this may display sensitive information to the end user.

Answer (score 0):

Check: IIS->Application pool->Advanced settings->.NET Framework Version 
if there are no .NET 4.0 you'll try to call `aspnet_regiis.exe -i`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx